How cheap would rocket fuel have to be to make Mars colonization feasible (according to Musk)?
Elon Musk tweeted recently:

SpaceX created the first fully reusable rocket stage and, much more importantly, made the reuse economically viable.
Making life multiplanetary is fundamentally a cost per ton to Mars problem.
It currently costs about a billion dollars per ton of useful payload to the surface of Mars. That needs to be improved to $100k/ton to build a self-sustaining city there, so the technology needs to be 10,000 times better. Extremely difficult, but not impossible.

Currently, launching Falcon Heavy costs \$90M. \$0.5M of this cost is fuel. But if technology costs were reduced by a factor 10,000, as Musk wants (through reuse, economies of scale, etc.), then fuel cost would dominate by a large margin.
Reaching Mars requires energy. On top of this, rockets waste most of their propellant accelerating the remaining propellant (rather than the payload).
Taking that into account (and ignoring the rocket's dry mass, for simplicity), I wonder how cheap the propellant would have to be to make the cost of reaching Mars equal $100k/ton?

There's the cost of making and storing the propellants on the ground (which is probably very small compared to everything else) and the cost of shipping that propellant to space which may be needed several times to boost the payload all the way out of Earth's gravity and on to a trajectory that will intercept Mars (which is probably very expensive compared to everything else)

@uhoh Let's say shipping 1kg to LEO requires 100kg of propellant. Then, the cost of 1kg of propellant in LEO equals the cost of 101kg of propellant here on Earth. One is a function of the other. My question is about the cost of the propellant here on Earth.

OK got it. My impression is that the cost of making and storing methane (or RP-1) and oxygen, even ultrapure and cryogenic, has always been pretty small, but that may not be true considering the huge volumes necessary and the plummeting cost of the cost of ownership of reusable rockets, so wow maybe this is now a significant factor!

Propellant is not the major cost. What SpaceX changed was not throwing away the rockets.

@OrganicMarble Certainly it never has been in the past, but the way rockets and engines are being simplified, manufacturing costs are trending down and reusability is increasing, by the time SpaceX will be going to Mars, I'm not sure that propellant costs will still be so small as to be insignificant.

Because of having to both lift and accelerate propellant, rocket designers are already going to extreme lengths to increase efficiency of rocket engines and also reduce weight as a way to reduce the amount of fuel they have to carry. I'm not sure that the price of fuel going up or down would have any real effect on how hard they work to achieve that. I'm not negating your question just pointing out that fact. The price of fuel making or breaking a giant effort like colonization probably would matter only if the finances were at the absolute breaking point already and it became the last straw.

Even then, various operations and amortization costs are likely to be bigger than just the raw propellant cost.

One option might be to create fuel on the moon and ship it to LEO – that would somewhat decouple the fuel price on earth from the fuel price in LEO.

Note: Musk is big on solar energy production, so own solar farm = free energy. Methane can be made from CO2+H2o+energy = free. O2 from air = free. SpaceX will only pay for fuel if they buy, not make their own.

The overall question is good I just don’t understand the importance of this part “(technology cost greatly reduced) then fuel cost would dominate by a large margin” Let’s say my monthly transportation cost is 1000 dollars, which is 700 combined for car payment, insurance, maintenance etc., and 300 for fuel. Somehow I am able to drop the other costs to 50 per month. Now the 300 fuel cost looms larger than the rest. But other than perhaps pointing a spotlight at it, how does this fact change my overall situation?

@StevePemberton Calculation of profitability of Mars colonization. Assume the colonization brings a certain profit, say, produce souvenirs from local rocks and ship to Earth by Starship. Technological overhead of Starship is minimal, but you still need A LOT of fuel to deliver these Martian souvenirs (and get Starship back to Mars). The question is now, how much fuel for the roundtrip, per 1kg of souvenirs = how cheap fuel would need to be given set souvenir price to turn profit?

@sf - Still seems like a spotlight effect. Let’s say I am an Uber driver, and I can only generate 500 in revenue. In my previous example with total cost 1000 I cannot make a profit. Then my other costs drop to 400, fuel is still 300, total cost 700, still no profit. Then my other costs drop to 150, fuel is still 300, total cost 450 so now I am profitable. All without a change in fuel price, and even though fuel is now my major cost. In the middle example where my other costs were 400 (total cost 700), if fuel prices dropped below 100 I would be profitable, even though fuel is not my major cost

A much better discussion than I'd have expected. || Along the way we get nuclear fusion power, space elevators and high energy ion-drives.

Frame challenge
This number has no basis in reality (other than possibly being a reverse calculation on the base of an available budget, see below). The quote is typical provocative Elon talk, just more provocative than usual.
Comparisons: Just no.
With \$100k/t, a 100t mission would only gross 10 million dollar. Even a 100t cargo plane costs about 400 million dollar but is re-usable many more times at at much lower cost. One simply cannot build a spaceship for a fraction of that, even if it can be flown a few dozen times. In fact, the money would be spent before a single sheet of steel has been bought, before a single screw has been turned, before a single joint has been welded or a single ton of fuel loaded into a tank that has not been built on incidental cost like salaries and facilities. The Cargo Lifter disaster is an example: 300 million Euros were burnt even though no vessel was ever built (but they left a very nice hangar behind).
Another comparison point is air-shipping a metric ton with UPS across the Atlantic: That costs apparently about \$26,000. Note that the airplane is fully reusable hundreds of times before the first major overhaul, risk of loss is negligible, there is no need to climb out of Earth's gravity well and there is a landing strip and full infrastructure at the destination.
He just wants to float a radical idea to make us think, and think big. Fair enough.
Likely origin of the number
While this number is not based on any physical reality it may have been conceived simply by reverse-calculating from known financial restrictions: By computing the maximum affordable cost per ton, given a certain budget and a certain tonnage. Some plausible numbers fit that assumption quite nicely: Elon has repeatedly floated the number of 1 million inhabitants of his envisioned Mars colony. We can assume a ton of necessary equipment per person (after all, a self-sustaining colony will need an industrial infrastructure). With \$100,000/t, the overall cost would amount to 100 billion dollars, which is in the ballpark of what Elon can cough up if he makes an effort. By contrast, even 1 trillion dollars is probably too much for Elon, and he really despises joint ventures and collaborations.1 Therefore, I believe that \$100,000 simply reflect Elon's assumed budget.
Side note
As the numbers show, a self-sustaining colony on Mars will not happen with current technology. The super high cost invites scrutiny and thus serves to expose the general nonsense of the idea — it needs to be economically viable lest it bankrupt Elon. If it were cheap, like tunnels, he could just go for it and fail. The arguments invalidating the idea have been out there for years. Chiefly among them is that Earth is so much better for us than Mars — even after a nuclear war or two, with a nuclear winter and  and radiation from fallout, mutations, cancer,  and 1% of the population left so much better. The cancer rate might still be lower. Let that sink in for a second.
To make space colonization likely a scientific revolution would be needed, in order to bring the cost and resource needs down. A space elevator might take us a step closer but might not be sufficient (it is still too costly and the capacity may not not sufficient). There are also a host of more interesting things one can do in space, like mine asteroids that are not in a gravity well. An anti-gravitation device or a way to sap energy from some unknown dimension (without collapsing the universe; I'm not joking!) or at least an Epstein Drive would be more like it.

 1It is likely that the cost would be another one or two orders of magnitude higher, a sum that could only be produced by a world government. Ironically, such a government would invalidate some of the risks for civilization on Earth, making it less urgent to establish a self-sustaining Mars colony.

I'm aware that I'm spoiling the party but I'd still appreciate feedback if people disagree because I think everything I say is trivially true (except, maybe that there are cheaper carriers than UPS).

I think the $100k/ton figure is probably wrong too, but I don't understand this answer.  There's no reason to suppose that cargo missions would necessarily have crew; every Starship flight has been uncrewed. Dragon routinely flies to ISS uncrewed. Crew aren't necessary. "The money would be spent..." sentence isn't speaking to a $100k/ton shipping cost, it's speaking to total program cost (or maybe ship cost).

You're jumping from one extreme to another. First, you say we can’t build a Mars colony, then you suggest that we need antigravity to make it realistic—both are pretty extreme positions. Starship is a great stepping stone for establishing space-based infrastructure, which can pave the way for further developments. There are also several alternative ways to access space more affordably, such as skyhooks, orbital rings, StarTram, and others. If you're interested, Isaac Arthur has an excellent series on these topics called Upwards Bound

@TheRocketfan I said "we can't build it with current technology", and then I said what would be necessary. That's not a jump.

@ErinAnne "Probably wrong" is very timid. I suppose they'd have crew for contingency and efficiency (there may only be so many launch windows so one may plan combined missions). And even if you have cargo and crew flights separated you must consider the crew cost for the cargo cost as well, in my book (the cargo's only use is to sustain the crew on Mars). Also, it is just a way to say "ridiculously little money, you cannot even pay the incidental mission costs", basically, before you have built or flown anything.

@ErinAnne As an aside, re: "Every Starship flight has been uncrewed": Ain't we glad? ;-)

@Peter-ReinstateMonica a fictional technology such as antigravity isn’t a viable alternative for real life

Space elevators using nanotubes seem more feasible than anti-gravitational devices to me.

@MWB Of course. That's why I mention it first. It is anything but clear whether it is actually doable. Even if, it's a first step only. I think capacity is quite limited, it's still not free, you are still only in orbit etc.

@TheRocketfan My entire point is that a Mars colony is about as realistic as an anti-gravity device, which is basically a requirement. As an aside, I think it would be foolish to assume that comparable discoveries are impossible. Exactly the feeling that particle physics is stuck and that progress in physics has stalled resembles, in my opinion, the situation in the late 1800s and may be a sign that we are at the eve of fundamental new discoveries that invalidate everything we seem to know, the way quantum and relativity theories did. Thinking we have reached the end is naive.

Saying that anti-gravity would be absolutely required to colonize Mars is just as extreme as saying one could walk all the way. Getting to LEO cheaply is going to be a solved problem soon, and something like Starship could also handle the LMO to Martian surface part (with propellant produced on Mars). So that leaves us with just the LEO to LMO bit, some 5 km/s delta-V. Using chemical rockets for that would be silly, but building a nuclear electric powered shuttle spacecraft is already almost possible. …

… According to my back-of-an-envelope calculation, a single AEPS engine can deliver that dV over 100 days to a ton of payload using some 13 kW of power. Take a few hundred of them and a modest reactor (smaller than those on nuclear submarines) and you're already sort of getting there. What remains is getting rid of the waste heat, which is quite an engineering challenge, but nowhere near as bad as building an anti-gravity device.

@TooTea Yeah, walking home... ;-)

@TooTea Btw, I didn't say "absolutely", that would be silly. I said "basically".

"$100k does not even cover the salary of a single astronaut during the flight " Uh what? The salary is going to be amortized over many many tons of cargo. Airplanes don't have 29 crew (A380) to fly one person.

This is the best answer, but I think you should lead with your best argument. Rather than discussing astronaut salaries, you should start with the UPS quote. Airliner airframes can survive up to 75,000 flights and the engines, at least 12,000 flights. Matching that reusability is probably a long way off. Also, jets have the advantage that the oxidizer doesn't have to be carried and only a day or two of food for the crew needs to be carried.

I agree with this. The cost of getting to Mars is a tiny fraction of the cost of keeping people alive there. And we don't even know yet how to do that part. Poisonous dust, thin atmosphere, solar radiation, low gravity, ...

To make spaceflight 10,000 times cheaper, rocket fuel wouldn't just have to be free; you'd have to be paid for using it.
To calculate cost per trip, and avoid debates about how long the rocket will last, let's do a perpetuity value calculation, which assumes it will last forever.
Currently we have a USD 150M cost per Falcon Heavy sized rocket with a 17-ton payload to Mars. A round trip to Mars takes 21 months, so the rocket can make that trip every 2 years. The standard discount rate is 10%. The calculation goes as follows:
Value of an annual perpetuity is V = P/r, where P is Price per trip and r is the discount rate = 0.1
Adjusted discount rate ar for 1 payment every 2 years is ar = (1+r)^2−1 = (1+0.1)^2-1 = 0.21
The value of a rocket that makes a trip every 2 years is thus V = P/0.21, where P is price per trip.
Net present value is NPV = V−C, where C is initial cost.

Solving for P, with NPV = 0 and C = $150 million:
P = C*0.21 = $150M*0.21 = $31.5 million

So, each trip will need to earn 31.5 million to break even for its initial construction.
100k/ton will earn 1.7 million per trip, out of the 31.5 needed. To break even, the rocket's 545 tons of fuel would need a negative cost of -180 USD per kilogram.
How cheap does it have to be to work? Assuming a 1.7M budget per trip, and that you could get fuel at 1.4 USD/kg, the remaining amortization budget is 1M/trip. The rocket has to be built for just 5 million USD.
Let's first look at the payload part. The cheapest aircraft that can carry 17 tons of payload is the 737, which has a list price around 90 million, and a minimum sale price after the Max disasters of 40 million. So you have to build a reusable spacecraft, with a 30-year service life, 8 times cheaper than the oldest still-produced airliner.
Can the price be cut further? The Falcon only has 28 tons of dry mass to begin with, and we've assumed very cheap fuel. Whatever is being transported to Mars has to be built at least to aviation standards, which involve a cost of 1,000/kg on average.
Let's go down to car standards. To buy enough tanker trucks to fit the Falcon's 545 tons of fuel, you'd need 27 trucks, which at 225k/truck (taking the high end, if we want to go to space) comes down to 6 million. Still above the goal. You'd have to build rocket engines cheaper than diesel V8s, and spaceworthy cryogenic tanks cheaper than plain steel trucks.
It's not so much the fuel cost as it is the long trip time, that places sub-million/ton missions to Mars firmly into the realm of non-science fiction.

can you elaborate on the NPV calculation?  It's not clear to me, as an aerospace engineer, how $30 million / trip for infinite trips is required to break even on a $150 million initial investment, and I suspect I'm not alone among the Space SE crowd.

@ErinAnne Well, it's a pretty simple V=P/r, where P is annual earnings and r is the discount rate... But I've added a detailed calculation with granularity accounted for.

I agree that's a simple calculation, but I'm not really clear on why you'd use the calculation for "an investment asset that pays a stated return for an infinite amount of time" for the return-on-value for a rocket sending supplies to Mars. If the rocket earns 1/5 of its cost per trip in profit (I know that's not quite the number you showed, I'm just simplifying the ratio), how hasn't it earned back its construction cost in five trips?  How is the sixth trip not profit over the construction cost?

@ErinAnne Because you either build the rocket on credit, or you could have invested that money elsewhere. Time value of money is usually estimated at 10%/year. If the rocket earns 1/5 of its cost per trip, in five trips you've only paid off 60% of the principal+interest.

I like this answer a lot, but I thinkit would benefit from substantial shortening and restructuring.  Here's how I would do it: 0) short summary of the main point 1) explain the economic logic (an investment has to not only break even bu beat other easier/less risky opportunities) 2) do the calculation but per tonne of capacity  to avoid linking to specific spacecraft, possibly varying costs fir fuel/discount rate 3) compare to cost per tonne of capacity of other systems.
